# Can't get the Android layout I want

Tags: android, android-layout

The below layout gets put into a list view on a separate tab but I'm struggling with this view for my custom adapter.

The first imageView id 'icon' I want on the left. The textView id 'item' I want in the middle to the right of id icon and the textView  'textView1' I want underneath the item which is okay as this is fine even the text to the right of icon is fine.

The problem I am having is with the id pause and id icon2. I want these to the far right of the textviews and imageviews above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4CBE99"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pause"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="420dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312"
            ads:adSize="200x80"
            android:layout_weight="3.40"></com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

[image]

Comment: It is better you show image or screen shot of what you plan to achieve. It will help

Comment: @Inducesmile is the above okay?

Comment: so this is a layout for rows in a list?

Comment: @Mehmed yes I have the rows already and the icon, item and textview 1 in the right place. I just need pause and icon2 to sit to the far right.

Comment: what about the `NativeExpressAdView`? Is it necessary or do you want it to cover whole bottom?

Comment: You can ignore that I already set the views to be gone at that point. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for each List item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4CBE99"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I think the NativeExpressAdView will be in the same layout with your Listview.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `ConstraintLayout` without nesting layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4CBE99"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/pause"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/pause"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add the following line to the dependencies in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and added the dependency but it shows errors like Error:(31, 46) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf' with value '@id/pause').

Comment: Yeah, that's an error, I have updated the XML, could you try it again?